# fingerprint - GUI and 18.04 login issue

Tags: login, 18.04, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I installed fingerprint GUI in my laptop having Ubuntu 18.04.

But I am not able to login using fingerprint while in terminal using `sudo` commands it is working fine but for login it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Alexey Please justify how it is not a duplicate in your comments here.

Comment: @ThomasWard, the other question asks how to use the fingerprint scanner under Ubuntu 16.04. This question asks what to do if the fingerprint scanner does not allow to log in in Ubuntu 18.04 after the relevant software was installed.

Comment: See also ["Fingerprint-GUI login ISSUE with new 18.04 LTS"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1062655).

Comment: Could you try `sudo pam-auth-update`?  See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114720) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Then, I registered my fingerprints to the application.

But when I am opening my laptop it is asking me to type password while it should open using fingerprint.

But the commands which require password are getting executed just by fingerprint and do not require any password